# How to Convert Images,Pdf ,Docx and Doc file to Bitmap

Tags: android, pdf, docx, doc

I'm using code for image convert to bitmap:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap() throws IOException {
        if (!getInformation())
            throw new FileNotFoundException();

        if (!getStoredDimensions())
            throw new InvalidObjectException(null);

        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, storedWidth, storedHeight);
        orientation.mapRect(rect);
        int width = (int) rect.width();
        int height = (int) rect.height();
        int subSample = 1;

        while (width > MAX_WIDTH || height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width /= 2;
            height /= 2;
            subSample *= 2;
        }

        if (width == 0 || height == 0)
            throw new InvalidObjectException(null);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = subSample;
        Bitmap subSampled = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resolver.openInputStream(uri), null, options);

        Bitmap picture;
        if (!orientation.isIdentity()) {
            picture = Bitmap.createBitmap(subSampled, 0, 0, options.outWidth, options.outHeight,
                    orientation, false);
            subSampled.recycle();
        } else
            picture = subSampled;

        return picture;
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is how to convert to Bitmap from Pdf ,Docx and Doc  extension file.
Are there any common functions for file conversions to bitmap.
I want to send to server files in bitmap.

Comment: Please share your views are here I 'm stuck in issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Retrofit for convert all types of files to  Bitmap.by using this Retrofit very easy and effortless to convert into bitmap android